# Multiple currency orderBy query

Tags: mysql, currency

How can I do a `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY item.price ASC` condition on a multiple currency database table?

I'm not sure if it is possible.

Item table has `price, currency` properties with a lot of  currencies of all types.

Comment: Are you asking how to take the currency into account (e.g., 1 GBP is worth more than 1 USD)?

Comment: Yeas, thats the point...

Comment: Do you have an exchange rates table?

Comment: No, a thinking how implement that, considering the exchange rates can change at every hour...

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to have another table with a conversion rate which would allow you to express each `price` converted to a common currency. Your `ORDER BY` would then be done based on the common currency.

For example:

```
 SELECT item, price as local_price, price * common_conversion_rate as comparison_price
 FROM   item_table
 left join conversion_rates ON item_table.currency = conversion_rates.currency
 ORDER BY common_conversion_rate * price
```

The `conversion_rates` table then contains columns:

```
 currency    common_conversion_rate
   USD           1.0
   GBP           1.4
   ZAR           0.1
   ...
```

This assumes that you can just pull the `currency` from your `item` table and multiply it by a factor from the `conversion_rates` table.

Comment: The accuracy of your output will depend on the accuracy of your exchange rate table. If your output needs to change as exchange rates change, then put at datestamp on it, something like 'Accurate as of some_date'.